# C# Troubleshooting object serialization error

Tags: c#, serialization, soap

I'm having problems sending a soap request to a webservice.  I create an order, including an array of order details.  Then I send that order to the webservice.  Using fiddler, I'm able to see that the order gets passed correctly, but the order details don't show up.  I only get:

```
<order><orderDetails><orderDetail /></orderDetails><order>
```

I've tried changing orderDetails from an array of order details to an array of strings and they show up correctly in the request.  I also get the correct number of  in the order.  They're just empty.

Both classes were generated from the wsdl, so I don't know why orderDetail doesn't seem to be serializing properly.  I don't know how to get more error details.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

From my Reference.cs, generated from my web service:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://some.url")]
public partial class order {
    private orderDetail[] orderDetailsField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("orderDetails", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public orderDetail[] orderDetails {
        get {
            return this.orderDetailsField;
        }
        set {
            this.orderDetailsField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://some.url")]
public partial class orderDetail {
    private int productIDField;

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public int productID {
        get {
            return this.productIDField;
        }
        set {
            this.productIDField = value;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Sorry, after further research, this question could be simpler.  Basically I can serialize the order object but serializing the orderDetails object just returns me an empty object.  They seem to be declared the same way so I wonder if anyone knows why that might happen or how I can debug the serialization process.

Comment: Debugging the serialization now, thanks to this page http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2008/02/25/debugging-net-serialization-code/

Comment: I could be wrong, but have you tried changing XmlArrayItemAttribute("orderDetails", to XmlArrayItemAttribute("orderDetail", ?

Comment: How are you deserializing? This is almost certainly a namespace issue: you're sending with one namespace, but the receiver is expecting another.

Comment: XmlArrayItemAttribute("orderDetails") just controls the name used in the xml.  Changing it didn't have any effect.

Comment: The namespaces were correct.  I wasn't setting the Specified field.  Setting it fixed the problem.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the generated classes have a 'Specified' field for each field.

Setting

```
object.productIDSpecified=true;
```

Made it serialize properly.  Hopefully this helps someone else out.